# Popup confirmation on 'status' column change

Tags: column, modal-dialog, popup

I'm looking to create a popup dialogue box when a column called 'Status' is set to 'Complete'.  I want a popup box to ask "Confirm Complete?" with Yes or Cancel choices.  Obviously Yes will update the record with Status Complete (which I have applied a filter already working to show the record in an "Archived" view, and again obviously, Cancel will cancel the changes.

Is this possible?

thanks...

Comment: I guess you want to do that in the edit form, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I've set the list settings so that the edit form doesn't launch in a dialogue.

Comment: do you find a solution? In my way, it doesn't work in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 2):

You can hook into the PreSaveAction function and put your verification logic in here.

For example:

```
function PreSaveAction(){
  if($('select[title="Status"]').val() == "Completed"){
     var isConfirmed = confirm("Do you confirm task completion?");
     if (isConfirmed ) return true; //confirm changes
     $('input[name$="IOGoBack"]').click(); //cancel changes
  }
  return true;
}
```

For this you'll need jQuery. And as a side note, the selector based on title attribute can easily break in a multi-language site (because, if you change the display language, the title will change accordingly).

**Update:** I edited the function so that if the confirmation dialog returns false, the Cancel button click is triggered

Comment: Thanks for that, however, is there perhaps something I'm missing, perhaps format-wise, as when I go to Edit HTML source, the above code actually shows as text instead of becoming background code.

Comment: The best thing would be to edit the page in SPDesigner and put the code inside a <script> tag at the bottom of the page. Or, you can add a CEWP to the page, from the web UI, and link to an existing js file that you'll have created and put inside a doc library of your choice

Comment: I'm unable to use SPDesigner, the company does not allow us to use this. I've entered the line [code]<script type="text/javascript">[/code] in and this now sets it as code, however, I'm receiving an error with details... Message: Object expected
Line: 696
Char: 3
Code: 0

Comment: OK, so the CEWP is your plan B

Comment: If you have got SP 2013, you can also use script editor webpart.

Comment: @daryl did you reference jQuery correctly?

Comment: Not sure.  How would I do that and then I can confirm if I have or not.

Comment: Go to jquery.com, get a copy, upload it to a doc library on your site. Before the script tag you added previously, add another script tag with its src attribute pointing to jquery (eg: script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/site/someDocLib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: Sorry, can't do this, again comes down to lack of certain privileges and permissions.  I think I remember doing something a while back (perhaps attempting to create a print page!) that referenced jquery through an internet URL.

Comment: Here's a link to a CDN serving jquery: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> (see more here: http://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn)

Comment: Ok, no error message, code seems to be acceptable, but no popup box, so I'm going to go over the code to make sure I've not made any typos.

Comment: Sorry folks, but I've not been able to get it to work as it just doesn't popup when I select "Complete".  Any suggestions.

Comment: I'm sure the code works. You need to tell us exactly what you did, or we won't be able to sort it out for you. Also, it is not supposed to popup as you select "Completed", but when you click on Save

Comment: Apologies for not getting back earlier. I've gone to edit EditForm.aspx, adding a CEWP. I've then chosen to "Edit HTML source" and enter the following code-                <script language="javascript">

function PreSaveAction(){
  if($('select[title="Status"]').value == "Complete"){
     var isConfirmed = confirm("confirm task completion");
     if (isConfirmed ) return true; //confirm changes
     }
  return true;
}</script>                                                    After I save the page, I then edit a record, select the "Complete" selection from column "Status" then clicked Save.

Comment: Hope that makes sense. Apolies for the way the code looks in my previous post, not sure how to make it look like proper code.

Comment: I don't see the reference to jQuery.Also, you cannot be sure that the CEWP didn't strip out your code. Use a HTML Form webpart instead and put your code in the form content editor box. Don't forget to make sure to precede your code with the script tag referencing jQuery !