# Popup dialog to confirm a form

Tags: 2010, jquery, form, popup

I have a list, and when I want to add an element inside, I want a popup dialog to ask me for a confirmation. If cancel is clicked, it stays on the form, awaiting a user's action on the form ; And if OK is clicked, the form is validated and the element created.

I used this topic : [Popup confirmation on 'status' column change](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92206/popup-confirmation-on-status-column-change)

**But I don't understand how to validate the form with "OK", or just stay on the form with "Cancel".**

**And can you tell me why the popup box doesn't appear with this code** (the id is the one of the "Register" button in the form) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#ctl00_m_g_9ff78e92_ed40_4212_ae0f_44b787664fa8_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem" ).click(function() {


             var isConfirmed = confirm("Confirmez-vous ce choix de réforme ?");
             if (isConfirmed == true) {

             }
             else {

             }

    });

})
```

I have this scipt JS in Sharepoint Designer, and I have a script tag referring to it in the html of the list. **There is no error with the file** (verified with the console in the browser).

**EDIT**

HTML in a webpart above the list :

```
<div id="ConfirmPopup" style="display: none;">
<div id="messageDiv" style="height: 100px; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; font-weight: bold;">
<label id="lblConfirmationMessage"> /label&gt;
</label></div>

<div id="buttonDiv" style="float: right; padding-right: 5px;">
<input type="button" value="Yes" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.Yes, &#39;Yes&#39;); return false;" style="width: 75px;"/>
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel, &#39;Cancel&#39;); return false;" style="width: 75px;"/>
<asp:hiddenfield runat="server" id="hdnButtonClicked">
</asp:hiddenfield></div>
</div>



<div id="InformationBox" style="display: none;">
<div id="Div2" style="height: 100px; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; font-weight: bold;">
<label id="lblInformationMessage"> /label&gt;
</label></div>
<div id="Div3" style="float: right; padding-right: 5px;">
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.Yes, &#39;Cancel&#39;); return false;" style="width: 75px;"/>
</div>
</div>





​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​<script src="/sites/DevNum/testjd/SiteReformeTest/js/jquery.js"></script>

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​<script src="/sites/DevNum/testjd/SiteReformeTest/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​<script src="/sites/DevNum/testjd/SiteReformeTest/js/popup_confirm.js"></script>​​​​​
```

JS popup_confirm.js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#ctl00_m_g_9ff78e92_ed40_4212_ae0f_44b787664fa8_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem" ).click(function() {


             /*var isConfirmed = confirm("Confirmez-vous ce choix de réforme ?");
             if (isConfirmed == true) {

             }
             else {

             }*/


             // Call openDialog method on button click or on page load
            function OpenConfigurationDialog(ConfirmationMessage) {

            var cloneModalContent = document.createElement('div');
            $("#lblConfirmationMessage").html(ConfirmationMessage);
            cloneModalContent.innerHTML = document.getElementById('ConfirmBox').innerHTML;

            var options = {
            html: cloneModalContent, // ID of the HTML tag
            // or HTML content to be displayed in modal dialog
            width: 375,
            height: 150,
            title: "Please Confirm",
            dialogReturnValueCallback: CloseDialog, // custom callback function
            allowMaximize: false,
            showClose: true
            };
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
            }


            // Call openDialog method on button click or on page load
            function OpenInformationDialog(InformationMessage) {
            var cloneModalContent = document.createElement('div');
            $("#lblInformationMessage").html(InformationMessage);
            cloneModalContent.innerHTML = document.getElementById('InformationBox').innerHTML;

            var options = {
            html: cloneModalContent, // ID of the HTML tag
            // or HTML content to be displayed in modal dialog
            width: 375,
            height: 150,
            title: "Error:",
            dialogReturnValueCallback: CloseDialog, // custom callback function
            allowMaximize: false,
            showClose: true
            };
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

            }

            function CloseDialog(dialogResult, returnValue) {
            if (returnValue == 'Yes') {
            document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
            return true;
            }
            if (returnValue == 'No') {
            return false;

            }
            if (returnValue == 'Cancel') {
            return false;
            }
            }


    });

})
```

And I'm sure the "Register" button of the form has this id : ctl00_m_g_9ff78e92_ed40_4212_ae0f_44b787664fa8_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem

Comment: Is my answer helped you to resolve your issue?

Comment: You haven't mentioned CloseDialog code to your button click. Please add it.

Answer (score 1):

On your `saveitem` button click event call below method

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#ctl00_m_g_9ff78e92_ed40_4212_ae0f_44b787664fa8_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem" ).click(function() {


             /*var isConfirmed = confirm("Confirmez-vous ce choix de réforme ?");
             if (isConfirmed == true) {

             }
             else {

             }*/
OpenConfigurationDialog("Confirmez-vous ce choix de réforme ?");




    });

// Call openDialog method on button click or on page load
            function OpenConfigurationDialog(ConfirmationMessage) {

            var cloneModalContent = document.createElement('div');
            $("#lblConfirmationMessage").html(ConfirmationMessage);
            cloneModalContent.innerHTML = document.getElementById('ConfirmBox').innerHTML;

            var options = {
            html: cloneModalContent, // ID of the HTML tag
            // or HTML content to be displayed in modal dialog
            width: 375,
            height: 150,
            title: "Please Confirm",
            dialogReturnValueCallback: CloseDialog, // custom callback function
            allowMaximize: false,
            showClose: true
            };
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
            }


            // Call openDialog method on button click or on page load
            function OpenInformationDialog(InformationMessage) {
            var cloneModalContent = document.createElement('div');
            $("#lblInformationMessage").html(InformationMessage);
            cloneModalContent.innerHTML = document.getElementById('InformationBox').innerHTML;

            var options = {
            html: cloneModalContent, // ID of the HTML tag
            // or HTML content to be displayed in modal dialog
            width: 375,
            height: 150,
            title: "Error:",
            dialogReturnValueCallback: CloseDialog, // custom callback function
            allowMaximize: false,
            showClose: true
            };
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

            }

            function CloseDialog(dialogResult, returnValue) {
            if (returnValue == 'Yes') {
            document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
            return true;
            }
            if (returnValue == 'No') {
            return false;

            }
            if (returnValue == 'Cancel') {
            return false;
            }
            }

})
```

You can get the reference of above code from [this link](http://www.tekritisoftware.com/sharepoint-custom-modal-pop-up-confirmation-dialog-box)

Comment: ok thanks, I used the tutorial, but even if I don't have any error, The popup doesn't appear. I add the complete code in my question

Comment: have you added opendialog code within your button click event? I have updated my answer. please look into it.

Comment: If you look at my edit in my question, I have put the code in the click function, tell me if I'm doing wrong

Comment: yeah nothing appends, I don't understand, even adding the closedialog function

Comment: ok I think the click function doesn't work well, I do some tests and come back here after

Comment: Try updated answer & debug the code

Comment: Ok I've understood that the html and so js are not called in the add element form because it's another "page". So this script doesn't work even if the code is in the list html. Do you know how to make this script working on the form ?

Comment: You can use Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScript code to register the whole function to Form (From where the form opens means on the parent page you should put this code to register entire JS to work it in Form).

Comment: Your First & Simple code will also work for you.

Comment: sorry now the script is on the form, but when I click register, nothing appears and the element is validated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38678/discussion-between-hardik-and-jey10).

Comment: yes, but I need to go, can we have this chat at 3:30 pm? It would be great, or another time if you can't at this time

Comment: Click on the link for discussion. I am already available over there